Is cause of undervalued currency the low cost of labor force or vice versa?
I read in some source that cause of undervalued currency is low cost of labor force.
In another source I read that low cost of labor force is conclusion of undervalued currency.
What case is true and why?
Thanks.

Could you please add the sources you are referring to?


https://www.banki.ru/news/columnists/?id=10718711 2.https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A0_1961_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F


This needs more details and/or clarity. As it stands you're asking people to go read an article and a wikipedia page and whether they come to the same conclusion as you.
